# Weird Segmentation fault error in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am on mac ox. I am trying to compile this simple program of Dynamic Array but I am getting a segmentation fault on realloc I believe when I try to grow my array

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAX_SIZE = 5 };

typedef struct dynamic_array{
    int maxsize;
    int size;
        int* items;
}DArray;

extern int  init(DArray *DAP);
extern void add(DArray *DAP, int val);
extern void addToSize(DArray *DAP,int val);
extern void destroy(DArray *DAP);
extern void print(DArray *DAP);
static int  full(DArray *DAP);
static int  grow(DArray *DAP);

int init(DArray* DAP)
{
    DAP->items = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_SIZE);
    if(DAP->items == NULL)
        {
        printf(" ALLOCATION OF DAP ITEMS NOT SUCCUESSFULL \n ");
        return 0;
    }
    DAP->maxsize = MAX_SIZE;
        DAP->size = 0; //initial size -> 0
    return 1;
}

void print(DArray* DAP)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < DAP->size; i++)
    {
        int* itemLocation = (DAP->items + sizeof(int) * i);
        printf(" \n ITEM AT LOCATION %d is %d \n ",i,*itemLocation);
    }
}

void add(DArray* DAP,int value)
{
    //add item at the end of the array, we can get the position by size counter?
    if(full(DAP) == 0)
    {
                addToSize(DAP,value);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" \n ********************* REALLOCATING AS SIZE == MAX SIZE %d %d ********************* \n ",DAP->size, DAP->maxsize);
        int result =  grow(DAP) == 1 ? 1 : 0;
        if(result == 0)
        {
            printf(" \n ********************* GROW NOT SUCCESSFULL ********************* \n " );    
        }else if(result == 1)
        {
            printf(" \n ********************* GROW SUCCESSFULL *************************** \n ");
            addToSize(DAP,value);
        }
        else
            exit(1);
    }
}

int full(DArray* DAP)
{
    int result = DAP->size == DAP->maxsize ? 1 : 0;
    return result;
}

void addToSize(DArray* DAP,int value)
{
        int* location = DAP->items + DAP->size;
        *location = value+1;
        printf(" \n AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  %d %d \n ", DAP->size,*location);   
        DAP->size++;
}

int grow(DArray* DAP)
{
    int* temp = (int *)realloc(DAP->items,DAP->maxsize * sizeof(int) * 2);
    if(!temp)
    {
        printf(" ********************* REALLOC NOT SUCCESSFULL ********************* \n ");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        DAP->items = temp;
        DAP->maxsize *= 2;
        //sanity check
        printf(" \n ********************* AFTER REALLOCATION CHECK AGAIN ********************* \n ");
        print(DAP);
        return 1;
    }
}

void destroy(DArray* DAP)
{
    if(DAP != NULL)
    {
        if(DAP->items != NULL)
        {
            free(DAP->items);
              DAP->items = 0;
              DAP->maxsize = 0;
                  DAP->size = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    DArray darray;
    if(init(&darray) == 1)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            add(&darray,i);
        }
    }

    print(&darray);
    destroy(&darray);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the weird part is in my realloc for the 2nd parameter where I declare the size element as -> `DAP->maxsize * sizeof(int) * 2`, it throws the segmentation fault when the array grow is called. Weirdly now, if I try to remove one of the constants to multiply something like just `DAP->maxsize * sizeof(int)` then it doesn't throw the segmentation fault error. I am not sure if something is wrong in my code or somewhere else.

******** Found the problem *********

The issue was inside the addToSize function. Changing the line of code from int* `location = DAP->items + (sizeof(int) * DAP->size);` to `int* location = DAP->items + DAP->size;` solved it. Apparently the sizeof(int) caused some junk values to be passed in realloc. Thanks to Alan for this!

Comment: Have you run your program through gdb?

Comment: You should check if DAP isn't NULL before calling DAP->Items or DAP->maxsize or if DAP->items is a valid pointer.

Comment: dereferencing null pointer in your `init` call

Comment: If you remove the factor `2` and resize as `DAP->maxsize * sizeof(int)`, then you aren't really increasing the size.  What else can you resize as?

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. C is not C++.

Comment: Note: do not use all-uppercase names for variables. It is one of the  few commonly accepted naming styles in C to use all-uppercase identifiers for macros and enum-constants only.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -> Yes your are right and I know that it won't resize. But when I add the factor of 2 it gives me a segmentation fault error and doesn't compile further. If I remove the factor 2 or one of the factors, it compiles the entire program without the segmentation fault.

Comment: In your code there are a lot of `(DAP->items + sizeof(int) * i);` which will go out of bounds. The increment uses the pointer type so `DAP->items + i;` is what you want in these cases.

Comment: Memory corruption in `addToSize()`: `int* location = DAP->items + (sizeof(int) * DAP->size);`. Should be `int* location = DAP->items + DAP->size;`. Likely causing junk values to be passed to `realloc` later on.

Comment: @AlanAu - PERFECT! Thanks a lot. May I know in such situations how do I know there was a memory corruption on that line? The error "Segmentation Fault" doesn't really help much in such cases.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would downvote this question. It was a legit question in my opinion and I got the solution from the person who actually understood my problem

Comment: @Htlcs As suggested in the answer by dbush, valgrind is your friend for all memory related issues (it helps for other classes of problems too). valgrind would almost certainly have picked that up straight off the bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues I found.  First in `addToSize`:

```
int* location = DAP->items + (sizeof(int) * DAP->size);
```

Pointer arithmetic automatically knows to increase the pointer by increments of the pointer size, so multiplying by `sizeof(int)` causing you to go off the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior.  You should instead do this:

```
int* location = DAP->items + DAP->size;
```

Similarly in `print`:

```
int* itemLocation = (DAP->items + sizeof(int) * i);
```

Should instead be:

```
int* itemLocation = DAP->items + i;
```

For issues like this, Valgrind is very helpful in discovering them.

Edit:

Here's what valgrind showed when I ran your code through it.  The first message stating "Invalid write of size 4" points exactly to where the problem is.

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./x1
==8270== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8270== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8270== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8270== Command: ./x1
==8270== 

 AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  0 1 

 AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  1 2 
==8270== Invalid write of size 4
==8270==    at 0x80485F6: addToSize (x1.c:78)
==8270==    by 0x8048530: add (x1.c:49)
==8270==    by 0x8048721: main (x1.c:124)
==8270==  Address 0x401a048 is 12 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==8270==    at 0x4005B83: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==8270==    by 0x8048475: init (x1.c:22)
==8270==    by 0x8048701: main (x1.c:119)
==8270== 
==8270== Invalid read of size 4
==8270==    at 0x80485FB: addToSize (x1.c:79)
==8270==    by 0x8048530: add (x1.c:49)
==8270==    by 0x8048721: main (x1.c:124)
==8270==  Address 0x401a048 is 12 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==8270==    at 0x4005B83: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==8270==    by 0x8048475: init (x1.c:22)
==8270==    by 0x8048701: main (x1.c:119)
==8270== 


 AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  2 3 

 AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  3 4 

 AFTER ADDING TO ITEMS, location, VALUE  4 5 

 ********************* REALLOCATING AS SIZE == MAX SIZE 5 5 ********************* 
--8270-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--8270-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x48;  sp: 0x62a01ddc

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
==8270==    at 0x380348EE: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:244)
==8270==    by 0x380637F7: vgPlain_cli_malloc (replacemalloc_core.c:86)
==8270==    by 0x38002AD3: vgMemCheck_realloc (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:423)
==8270==    by 0x3806420B: do_client_request (scheduler.c:1370)
==8270==    by 0x380659CE: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1061)
==8270==    by 0x3808E9F8: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:91)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==8270==    at 0x4005C82: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:476)
==8270==    by 0x804864B: grow (x1.c:85)
==8270==    by 0x804855C: add (x1.c:54)
==8270==    by 0x8048721: main (x1.c:124)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! very very very helpful